# Does using multipart/form-data Content Type for a RESTful POST api a good practice?

Tags: json, rest, http, restful-architecture

I have a situation where I have to write a api to create a resource and amongst datafields that I need to accept is a string that is basically contents of a html file. As I see it I have a choice between structuring the entire thing as a json object where this field is a string field with urlencoded html string , and having the Content Type as multipart/form-data where each of the fields and the html string (UTF-8 encoded) is a part in the message. 
Not using json is something I am not comfortable with as I feel violating the REST standards in not structuring the content of the entity I am about to create thus there is a loss of information for the consumers as they can't tell immediately looking at my api definition about what data to feed to it. But practically multipart/form-data handles stuff like html file content better and more efficient as I will not have to urlencode it and can control the char-encoding also.
What will be a better approach in current context and upholding RESTful principles ? Also are there other trade-offs i should be aware of ? what about parsing a json with a huge string field (~ 200 Kb)embedded?
**EDIT** :- I was reading some similar questions on SO and one approach that stood out was the 2-step approach of making a first call with metadata to create the entity and then upload the file as an UPDATE process to the created entity wherein we use multipart/form-data. In that context, I guess , what I am asking is how sound is an approach where I send both metadata and the file in a single api call as multipart data , where each metadata field is actually a part in the multipart message as is the file.

Answer (score 4):

The canonical way to upload files to REST API is using the multipart/form-data. As W3 recommendation guide says:

> The content type "multipart/form-data" should be used for submitting
>   forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and binary data.

Multipart/form-data has advantages over base64 to represent binary data. Is sticked to REST/Http philosophy, and simplify the develop of API clients.

[Returning values from Forms: multipart/form-data](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt)

[W3 Recommendation guide](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)

Comment: That is incorrect, that is canonical way to upload file using HTML forms. It does not say anything about using it in REST API.

Answer (score 1):

The good practice is to use multipart/form-data whenever files are uploaded to the server along with database fields. Do not send a base64 JSON string as the request to your Rest API as it might corrupt the file or degrade the performance of your application.

As far as documenting multipart/form-data Rest API for your consumers is concerned you have to force your API consumers to use the same form fields which you have predefined in your web service.

[Returning Values from Forms:  multipart/form-data](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt)

Answer (score 1):

I started using FormData objects everywhere on the client-side, in lieu of regular form input fields, for dynamic REST posts. FormData is presented in a positive light in various tutorials, so I went with it.

However, down the line, this caused me problems when decoding the form data into my Go structs. FormData objects are sent as "multipart/form-data" (regardless of files being sent) and I believe my decoder in Go didn't convert the raw data back to string form. Eventually my SQL queries were throwing panics, as hex data was being sent in where strings should have been.

So with some adjustment, I could use FormData however I've decided to revert to the simple universal recommendation: Use "multipart/form-data" only for special cases like when sending files. Otherwise, just use regular "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".