# JHipster - File upload - multipart/form-data vs base64 - application/json

Tags: http, jhipster

After importing an entity (e.g. Car) from JDL studio with one field as a Blob I notice that the generated code looks like this:

```
this.dataUtils.toBase64(file, (base64Data) => {
    car[field] = base64Data;
    car[`${field}ContentType`] = file.type;
});
```

i.e. the file is base64 encoded and subsequently sent with `content-type:application/json`.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33359925/2440661) post, it seems that the canonical way to upload files to a REST API is using the `multipart/form-data` (as per W3 recommendation).

For my curiosity, I'm just wondering why base64 / `application/json` was used as opposed to `multipart/form-data`.

Thanks,

Comment: I guess only @pgrimaud who wrote this part could answer but I would say that it could be to use same approach for both download and upload.